# Dropdown-menu:before inside ul

Tags: html, css

I want to ask, I have created dropdown menu list, but when in responsive mode, the `dropdown-menu:before` is not showing. I have set `margin-top`, but the `dropdown-menu: before` arrow is inside `ul list` menu. It happens only on mobile resolution (<768px). It should be outside `ul list` menu right ?

Here's the css code

```
.dropdown-menu{
top: 45px !important;
right: -320px;
left: -437px !important;
width: 460px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px -1px #c1c1c1;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding: 0px !important;
}
.dropdown-menu:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 12px;
  border:10px solid #343A40;
  border-color: transparent transparent #343A40 transparent;
}
```

Here's html code

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li></li><li></li><li></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Do you know how to make `dropdown-menu:before` outside the `ul list` menu box ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you add position:relative to the .dropdown class?

Comment: I have put position:relative, but its still not changed

Answer (score 1):

At first glance the main issue that you don't specify `position: relative` on `.dropdown-menu`.

So your `:before` pseudo-selector is not positioned relative to `.dropdown-menu`, but to some nearest parent with relative positioning.

Always keep in mind that elements with `position: absolute` positioned relative to nearest parent with `position: relative`.

`position: relative` on it's own won't help, because you weirdly position your elements.

Check it out https://codepen.io/fromaline/pen/zYBKMjp

Comment: It's just happen in mobile resolution (<768px). In normal resolution, it's working fine. When I tried put `position: relative` to `dropdown-menu`, the navbar menu on mobile resolution is broken

Comment: Yeah, it's because you apply `top`, `right` and `left` to `.dropdown-menu`, so when you add `position: relative` it brokes. You either need to position `.dropdown-menu` without `top`, `right` and `left` or position `:before` psedo-selector relative not to `.dropdown-menu`, but  to parent of `.dropdown-menu`. It's exactly the parent relative to which you position `.dropdown-menu`.

Comment: I've tried position `:before` psedo-selector relative to `.dropdown` because it's parent of `.dropdown-menu`. However, it's `:before` is always shows, how I made position `:before` only show when `.dropdown-menu` clicked ?

Comment: No, you don't need to make `.dropdown:before`, you need to poistion `.dropdown-menu:before` relative to `.dropdown`. Upload snippet with your issue to codepen or something similar, it's very hard to help just by comments :)

Comment: please check https://codepen.io/ikramshabri/pen/ExygGMq